# angular bootstrap modal backdrop not showing for bootstrap css version 3.3.2

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

change the css version to 3.3.2 in this plunker code and the backdrop won't appear when you open the modal.

from

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rzU6gQsjEP4R9sGKO2dl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a recently introduced [bug](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2970).

Add this CSS workaround:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround you can do

1- add this css class:

```
.modal-backdrop{
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
}
```

2- make sure the "window.html" template file included "ng-click" event

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)">
    <div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My only solution was:

```
.modal-backdrop.fade {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Hope it helps!